# What is the alternative instruction instead of writing many nested for loop in R?

Tags: r, string, for-loop, matrix

I have 29 matrix. I need to write 29 nested loops and in the last loop I should call a function on the 29-word string. But writing 29 loops is time consuming. Also, I have to repeat this procedure in another `R` code. I'm looking for an alternative way to implement these loops.
The code for what I explained is as follows. `m1` to `m29` are matrix and `make_rule_antc` is the function that I call on each element of the matrix:

```
    for (i1 in 1:nrow(m1)){

      for (i2 in 1:nrow(m2)){

       for (i3 in 1:nrow(m3)){
          .
          . 
          .

         for (i29 in 1:nrow(m29)){

             make_rule_antc(m1[i1,],m2[i2,],m3[i3,],...,m29[i29,])

         }
       }
     }
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want to do exactly? How large are our matrices? A better approach might be to do some data reshaping first.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be something like this:

```
m1=matrix(c(1,2,3,4), nrow = 2)
m2=matrix(c(1,2,3,4), nrow = 2)
m3=matrix(c(1,2,3,4), nrow = 2)

ms=list(m1,m2,m3)
idx=expand.grid(lapply(ms,FUN=function(x) seq(1,nrow(x))))
body=function(x) { 
  arglist=list()
  for (i in 1:length(x)) 
    arglist[[i]]=ms[[i]][x[i],]
  do.call(make_rule_antc, arglist)
}
apply(idx,MARGIN = 1, FUN=body)
```

Comment: this will fail in case `nrow(x) == 0`

Answer (score 0):

@cyberj0g solution can be simplified to this

```
m1 <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4), nrow = 2)
m2 <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4), nrow = 2)
m3 <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4), nrow = 2)
ms <- list(m1, m2, m3)

rows <- sapply(ms, nrow)
combination <- expand.grid(lapply(rows, seq_len))

apply(combination, 1, function(x){
  do.call(make_rule_antc, as.list(x))
})
```

Comment: You're just passing indexes to OP's `make_rule_antc` instead of actual matrix rows. However, I'm sure that my solution could be simplified.

Comment: Would you and @cyberj0g explain why m1, m2 and m3 are generated like this? I have 29 matrix. How should I use them in your codes?

Comment: Given you already have m1...m29, just add them to list in `ms` like this: ms=list(m1, m2, m3, m4,...,m29)